# Advanced solution from any fundamental solution

Tags: distribution-theory, fundamental-solution

Is there a way to calculate the advanced solution from a fundamental solution. Namely for $P$ a partial differential operator and $E$ a fundamental solution with $\text{supp} \ E =\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n $
$$ P(E) = \delta \ .$$
can I find a solution $E_+$ with $\text{supp} \ E_+ = \mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $P(E_+) = \delta$ ?

I know that in the reversed case $\tilde{E} := \frac{E_++E_-}{2}$ fullfills $P(\tilde{E}) = \delta$ .

For $H_t(t,x) := 1$ if $t \geq 0$ and $H_t(t,x) := 0$ if $t < 0$ I thought that maybe $E \ H_t$ could yield
$$
\left<P(E \ H_t ),\phi\right> = \left<P(E) H_t + E \ P(H_t),\phi\right> \\
= \left< \delta, \phi\right> \left< H_t, \phi\right> + \left<E,\phi\right> \left<P(H_t), \phi\right> .
$$
But then I don't know how to continue and whether this works for all fundamental or just the one gained from the fourier transform or not at all. Does anybody have a hint?

Comment: Ok so this can not work for all fundamental solution, since if $P(D)$ is hyperbolic with respect to $N$ there is only one fundamental solution with support in the corresponding halfplane $H := { x|<x,N> \geq 0}. This solution is in fact regular so has to do something with the fourier transform.

Comment: Or maybe there doesn't exist a solution?

Comment: What I understood so far is, that it is best to start from the fundamental solution created by the fourier transform $F := \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\frac{1}{p(\tau,\xi)}) $ for $p$ the polynomial with $p(\partial_\tau, \nabla \xi) = P$.

Comment: Also I am happy with the special case where the operator is of form $ P = L + M$ with $L$ only depends on derivatives of $\tau$ and $M$ only depends on derivatives of $\xi$.